# Where can I find the function "require" in the PHP source?

Tags: php, c

I have checked the PHP source code and can not find the "require" function.
I only found a piece code relatives to it on main/main.c from line 976

```
switch (EG(current_execute_data)->opline->extended_value) {
    case ZEND_EVAL:
        function = "eval";
        is_function = 1;
        break;
    case ZEND_INCLUDE:
        function = "include";
        is_function = 1;
        break;
    case ZEND_INCLUDE_ONCE:
        function = "include_once";
        is_function = 1;
        break;
    case ZEND_REQUIRE:
        function = "require";
        is_function = 1;
        break;
    case ZEND_REQUIRE_ONCE:
        function = "require_once";
        is_function = 1;
        break;
    default:
        function = "Unknown";
}
```

Do you know which file defines the "function"?

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_execute.c. Starting from line 4556, it looks like. You can use the Github search function for `ZEND_REQUIRE` to find all instances where that line shows up, which brought me to that file.

Comment: Hi @aynber, But it should has something like define require..., right?

Comment: There's the C define in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_compile.h on lines 969-972 as well as setting pseudo_function_name in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c at line 1836

Comment: Thanks @aynber, do you know how can call this function in the PHP extension (c)?

Comment: Sorry, that I don't know. I haven't actually messed with C in years and years, but I'm really good at searching GitHub!

Comment: I'm curious why an extension would need this. `require` and `include` are more language constructs or expressions rather than functions (which is why they don't need parentheses), although the C code might ultimately be implemented as a function. Can you explain the usage?

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, yes, that was why I put them inside the double quotes. I have used the “implementation” of this instead use the “function” but I got a memory leak issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679899/php-extension-use-of-uninitialized-memory-on-second-request?noredirect=1#comment130121883_73679899, that is why I want to use this “function”, because call directly the function easy to handle the memory leak

Comment: Thanks @MarkSmith. I've never built an extension, so I'm just trying to wrap my brain around why an extension would need this functionality in the first place. I would assume, possibly incorrectly, that the engine itself would take care of this for you before your code is invoked, unless of course your extension needs to run before the engine (possibly like XDebug), I guess. I absolutely believe whatever you are doing, I'm just curious.